i keep getting Error during variable generation in AnyLogic even though i've defined my dynamic variable in main properly and referenced it
i keep running into this error below, in my person agent the dynamic variable is being references with main to calculate the adoptionRate, so i dont get why it wont get parsed? i've defined the action of my dynamic variable clearly.Im not sure how to fix this
demand(getMonth()) / 200.0;

Error during model creation:
ERROR during variable generation:
Couldn't parse expression for adoptionFraction - Dynamic Variable: syntax error.
Please check expressions of this variable.
java.lang.RuntimeException: ERROR during variable generation:
Couldn't parse expression for adoptionFraction - Dynamic Variable: syntax error.
Please check expressions of this variable.
    at bass_diffusion_abm.Main.<init>(Main.java:521)
    at bass_diffusion_abm.Simulation.createRoot(Simulation.java:156)
    at bass_diffusion_abm.Simulation.createRoot(Simulation.java:1)


so i've tried to add main.demand and main.getMonth() but neither worked

There is a space in your code:

Start using code-complete and never type code yourself. It avoids issues like this and also shows you all the stuff you could do at a certain code point.
PS: Pls only use the "anylogic" tag, else you confuse 1000s of other SOF users that have no idea what "AnyLogic" is.
